# Delete php is not working

Tags: php

My database does not have unique id.

```
include('php_connect.php');

// check if the 'Userid' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
if (isset($_GET['ServerName']))
{
// get id value
    $userid = $_GET['ServerName'];     
// delete the entry
    $strSQL = "DELETE from server WHERE ServerName = (?)";
    $params = array($userid);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $strSQL, $params);
    if( $stmt ){
        sqlsrv_commit( $conn );
        echo "Record Deleted";
        }
    else
    {
        echo $params[0];
        echo "statement error.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    sqlsrv_close( $conn );    
}
else
// if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
{
    echo "WTH Something happened to the ServerName!.<br />";
    echo "Better start over.<br />";
}

?>
```

and the results is this:

```
WTH Something happened to the ServerName!
Better start over
```

Comment: Maybe the url does not contain `ServerName`, that's why is redirecting to `else`

Comment: Check your url. You need to call the php file with ServerName as a variable and some value. If your filename is like db.php.

It should be <YourPath>\db.php?ServerName='abc' . 

Then this error will be removed.

Comment: I think you really meant to put `$_GET['Userid']` rather than `$_GET['ServerName']`

Comment: can you share your url format?

Comment: ok i want to create a delete function, but i dont have any id with it... thats why i assigned userid to servername.
is there any function to solve my problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment on code you should check userid insted of servername :

check if the 'Userid' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid

```
if (isset($_GET['ServerName']))
{
```

To

```
if (isset($_GET['Userid']))
{
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie  // check if the  'Userid' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid check in code

Answer (score 0):

Change `$_GET['ServerName']` to `$_GET['Userid']`:

```
if (isset($_GET['Userid']))
{
    //rest of codes
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
 if(!$_GET['ServerName']){}
```

Comment: @Amin Hidaya replace `isset($_GET['ServerName'])` by `!$_GET['ServerName']`